# Search facets by title vs node id

Tags: views, search

I have [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api), [Search API Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) and [Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/facets) setup in drupal 8.  The view settings used as data source for the facet is as below.
[image: solr search view settings]

There are two content types: Language and Role.  Both are used as inline entities in other content types with field names: file_language and field_role.  The facet setting are as below:
[image: facet setting language]
[image]

However, in the facet browse view language is displayed with title link and role is displayed as node id link.
[image]

I am not sure which setting is causing this issue. How to display role by title, similar to language?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared the facet definitions via Dev module and noted the " Transform entity ID to label" option.  That does it.